# I can't get the right result for multiple-boolean operation

Tags: boolean

I'm very new to programming and I'm currently learning Python 3.X.

I'm keeping everything I learn separated in files while trying to make it neat and interactive.

So I created a file only about boolean variables and its operations, and I wrote the following exercise:

---

```
# Variables

sad = bool(input("Are you sad? "))

hungry = bool(input("Are you hungry? "))

tired = bool(input("Are you tired? "))
```

---

```
# Process

print("\nYou are sad, and hungry, and tired: ", sad and hungry and tired)

print("You are tired or hungry, but happy: ", (sad or hungry) and not sad)

print("You're not tired, or you're hungry or happy: ", not tired or hungry or not sad)
```

---

```
# Input:

sad = True 

hungry = False

tired = False

# Output:

You are sad, and hungry, and tired: True .......**should be False**

You are tired or hungry, but happy: False

You're not tired, or you're hungry,
```

---

I tried to put parenthesis between each pair of variables, but I'm getting the same output. What's happening? Am I not supposed to do this bool chain?

Comment: If `sad and hungry and tired` is True, then all three variables must by True, or Truthy. Double check your data.

Comment: I just tested this, and it outputs False as expected in the first case. If you're getting different results, you need to show a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The expression `bool(input('whatever'))` produces `True` whenever a non-empty response string is entered.  So if you are entering the word `No` and expecting the resulting `bool` value to be `False` then you're going to be disappointed.  You could get the outcome you want by doing something like `xyz = bool(input('are you xyz? ').lower == 'yes')`.  For more explanation see https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=bool#bool and https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth .  Also, your second `print` expression contains an obvious mistake.